# How to check if a method is called in nested jest mock functions

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a mock service like below

```js
  const firebaseService = jest.fn(() => ({
    initializeApp: jest.fn(() => { /*do nothing*/}),
  }))
```

in my test I want to `expect` if `initializeApp` has been called.
How can I check that?

```js
it('should be called', () => {
   expect(???).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

### Update : Real scenario

```
  const collection = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      doc: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          collection: collection,
          update: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
          onSnapshot: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))
        }
      }),
      where: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
          onSnapshot: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
          limit: jest.fn(() => {
            return {
              onSnapshot: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
              get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
            }
          }),
        }
      }),
      limit: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          onSnapshot: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
        }
      })
    }
  });

  const Firestore = {
    collection: collection
  }

    firebaseService = {
      initializeApp() {
        // do nothing
      },
      firestore: Firestore
    };
```

and I want to check below

```
 expect(firebaseService.firestore.collection).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(firebaseService.firestore.collection.where).toHaveBeenCalled();    
 expect(firebaseService.firestore.collection.where).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`assignedNumbers.123`, '==', true);
```

Comment: would it be easier to use mocking package like [`firebase-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-mock)? to me mocking such variety of methods manually might be really hard

Comment: @skyboyer I tried to use that, it mocks the methods (https://github.com/danleavitt0/firebase-mock/blob/master/src/firebase.js), but none of them are jest.fn, so I am not able to check if they are called or not, see this https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock/issues/150

Comment: but do you really need that? I mean if API is mocked - so you know what it responds - and component renders as expected - does it really matter what exact API calls has been done and when?

Comment: @skyboyer good point, what is the best practice? do we need to check if dependencies are called with specific args or just receiving mock response is enough?

Comment: don't have 100% confidence on that but since I've migrated from asserting everything to asserting only outcomes(wherever it component, independent function or model class) my tests stop breaking on each internal refactoring :) so I believe it's so named implementation details we should ignore for better unit testing. Just personal opinion though.

Answer (score 9):

You can define the inner spy as a variable.

```
const initializeAppSpy = jest.fn(() => { /*do nothing*/});

const firebaseService = jest.fn(() => ({
    initializeApp: initializeAppSpy,
}))
```

Then you can use the reference in order to `expect` on it:

```
it('should be called', () => {
   expect(initializeAppSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

**EDIT**
You can create a mock to the entire service

```
const firebaseMock = {
   method1: 'returnValue1',
   method2: 'returnValue2'
}

Object.keys(firebaseMock).forEach(key => {
   firebaseMock[key] = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(firebaseMock[key]);
});

const firebaseService = jest.fn(() => firebaseMock);
```

now, you will have a `firebaseMock` object that all the methods are mocked.
you can expect on each one of those methods.

Comment: You can define the entire returned object as spy. you can iterate over it, and call `jest.spyOn(obj, 'methodName')`.

Comment: you can describe object separately `mockPrototype = { init: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), getA: jest.fn(), ... }` and then describe module factory: `firebaseService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockPrototype);`. Don't forget to `.mockClear` each method in `beforeEach` or `afterEach` otherwise your test may fail or pass when they should not.

Comment: @skyboyer would you please explain it more, I didn't get what is the purpose of mockPrototype and methods inside

Comment: actually I mean something close to flixmosh answer update but instead of `method1: 'returnValue'` you may have `method1: jest.fn(), method2: jest.fn()` and on per-test basis you may mock return values by your needs: `firebaseMock.method1.mockReturnValue(111);` etc

Comment: key thing: `beforeEach(() => { firebaseMock.method1.mockClear(); firebaseMock.method2.mockClear(); ... })` or `for(const item of firebaseMock) item.mockClear();` to reset `.calls` prop so `toHaveBeenCalled` don't lie you

Comment: @felixmosh thanks for updated answer, also would you please add some code how to `expect` if `method1` has been called

Comment: @felixmosh please see my updated question with real scenario

Comment: You can do the same thing that I've mentioned on a nested object as well.